# Firebase optional crashes not showing up correctly

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I am using firebase crash reporting on a live app, there is only 1 version released to the app store. My console showed the `upload-dsym` message. I manually uploaded them via the terminal script,

```
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
 -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs
```

It showed me the message that the symbols are uploaded correctly.

Now the problem part, before uploading dsym files there were *two* types of crashes, one showed that dsym was required and several others that showed they were optional. Even though there were many crashes that were optional, none of them showed up in any statistics (i.e kept showing only 1 user as having 1 crash, if it helps the UUID of all crashes were different).

After uploading dsym to the console, the required crash appeared as normal in the issues listing but the optional ones are still in the missing dsyms.

So two questions:

1. Why don't the optional crashes appear on the statistics inside my dashboard?
2. Even after uploading dsysm (I know its correct since crash with the required status is in the issue list), the optional crashes don't appear properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640184/firebase-crashlytics-missing-optional-dsyms/61963873#61963873) should help you. To answer your questions, optional dSYMs don't map to entire crashes the same way required dSYMs do. With some optional dSYMs missing, you will likely see some crashes that have `(Missing)` in a few of the stackframes. Required dSYMs are the only dSYMs that stop crashes from being processed and ending up on your console entirely.

Comment: But that still doesn't explain why they don't appear on statistics?

Comment: Could you expand? I'm not sure what you mean by statistics.

Comment: By statistics i mean X number of users face Y number of crashes.

Comment: Optional dSYMs don't usually represent entire crashes. They are usually some frameworks/libraries that you have linked into your app, thus some of the stackframes that come from optional dSYMs may appear in some stacktraces. If you see `Missing` frames on a crash report, it's because we didn't have one of the optional dSYMs that those frames require.

Comment: Ohh I see, I thought optional just meant missing stack traces. But would still reflect on the count.

Comment: Yep, you can think of required dSYMs as corresponding to missing entire stacktraces, but optional as corresponding to missing some frames of a stacktrace!