Firebase Crashlytics Flutter/iOS [Missing optional dSYM]
I tried to setup run script and other requirements specified from the firebase documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter#set-up-dsym-uploading.
Currently As I see it, there are two dSYM. the required dSYM and the optional. this is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61963873/24020277
I think my question is how can I upload both the required and optional dSYM automatically, because currently It just uploaded the required dSYM not the optional. is there any additional configuration or flag that I missed out ?
enter image description here
I tried to configure build phase with $PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase script with -ai app_id and -- $DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/App.framework.dSYM.
And specifies the required input files based on the firebase documentation
